# Datetime string doesn't match after strftime() and strptime()

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

In a Django project, I store a Datetime Field in database.
I get the date string from web page, and use datetime.strptime() to convert to datetime type, and assign it to the DatetimeField. But when I get the field and use strftime to get the string, it is one day off, why is this happening?

```
datestr = "2013-12-12";
expireDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%d");
datamodel.time = expireDate;
datamodel.save();

# when I get the model in another method
expireDate = datamodel.time;
datestr = expireDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"); # I get "2013-12-11"
```

I think maybe it has something to do with timezone, but have no idea how to resolve it. Please help!

Comment: `expireDate = datamodel.time` what is the value when you do `print expireDate`?

Comment: what is your timezone in your settings file?

Comment: Are you using timezone support?

Comment: It is usually suggested to install [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) when enables timezone. Have a try?

Comment: I am using django timezone support. When I print expireDate when getting it out of model, I get this: datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>). My timezone settings in settings.py is TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing datetime objects, not just a date. This means that the time is set to midnight in your local timezone. Retrieving the datetime object again does so in the UTC timezone instead, which is 6 hours off for you.

Store the datetime object *with* a timezone:

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc

datestr = "2013-12-12"
expireDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%d")
datamodel.time = expireDate.replace(tzinfo=utc)
datamodel.save()
```

If you are handling *just* dates, you could also switch to using a [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) instead of `DateTimeField`:

```
datestr = "2013-12-12"
expireDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

`date` objects have no timezone associated with them.